# Obtain the response of the redirected page in PDF in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, wicked-pdf

I have a button in my app which redirects to a new window by clicking on it. Here is the jQuery code for it:

```
jQ("#create_report").click(function() {
        if (jQ('#client_id').val() !== "" && 
            jQ('#report_date').val() !== "") {
            window.open( 
                "/automated_reporting/report?clientId=" + 
                jQ('#client_id').val() + "&clientName=" + 
                jQ('#client_id option:selected').html() + 
                "&selectedDate=" + jQ('#report_date').val(), 
                'Report',
                'height=700,width=750');
            jQ('#modal_report').modal('hide');
        } else {
            jQ('#create_modal_notification').showMessage(
                "error", "Provide Date and Report Type"
            );
        }
    });
```

In my controller, I have written nothing for redirecting or rendering it, as I have already done it in the JavaScript. The page is redirected successfully and the output is also displayed properly as required. But what I want is to print the output of the redirected page in PDF format. I have tried to use the `wicked_pdf` gem for it by entering the following code in my controller's report action:

```
respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf do
              render :pdf => "file_name"
          end
      end
  end
```

But it just gives template error report.pdf does not exist and double render error when I try something else.

Answer (score 0):

Using pry on my app this is what works.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.pdf do                          
          pdf = OrderPdf.new(@order, view_context)
                 send_data pdf.render, filename: "serial_#{@order.id}-#{@order.first_name}.pdf",
                     type: "application/pdf",
                     disposition: "inline"
          end
end
```

I do not have the second render.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `report.pdf.erb` (I think) file?

I'm using wicked_pdf on my app and this works (but I have the `my_action.pdf.erb` file on my views):

```
def my_action 
    format.pdf do
        render :pdf => slug, :show_as_html => params[:debug]
    end
```